# Passing a simple macro as a function argument gives 'too few arguments in function call'

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

Okay, so this is a bit weird. I declared the following function:

```
void setMeshAttribute(int& ID, int attribute, int value);
```

And when I call:

```
setMeshAttribute(mesh_1_id, 0 ,0);
```

I get no problems whatsoever. But then I define

```
#define XE_MAX_VERTICES 0
```

and try:

```
setMeshAttribute(mesh_1_id, XE_MAX_VERTICES, 0);
```

I get an error at `XE_MAX_VERTICES`, telling me 'too few arguments in function call'. Now the way I see it, is that the compiler will just replace `XE_MAX_VERTICES` with 0 and everything should be fine. Apperently it isn't.

What am I doing wrong here?

If there is already a question addressing this kind of issue, please link to it, since I couldn't find one myself.

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be very hard to do anything but guess.

Comment: Look at the preprocessor output (-E flag for gcc).

Comment: As described it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, I was a s bit stupid when I typed the code instead of copy-pasting it.. look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this was just stupid. Instead of

```
#define XE_MAX_VERTICES 0
```

I had:

```
#define XE_MAX_VERTICES 0;
```

Also, the code in my question wouldn't have helped a lot, since the semicolon wasn't even in there.

Thanks to Joachim Pileborg for telling me my example had to be verifiable.